# How can I know how many rows were affected after an update query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm programming in PHP with a MySQL DB ... and i would like to know how many rows were affected after an update query... are there a php function or mysql query that can tell me how many..

Comment: Which php-mysql extension do u use?

Comment: Have you tried mysqli_affected_rows()? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `mysqli_affected_rows()` function as described here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

**Demo**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* update rows */
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```